# Expand/Collapse Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The code below works fine with ONE Reveal/Hide Text process

```
<div class="reveal">Click Here to READ MORE...</div>
<div style="display:none;">

<div class="collapse" style="display:none;">Collapse Text</div>
```

However if this code is duplicated multiple times, the Collapse Text shows up and doesn't disappear and in fact conflicts with the Expand to reveal even more text instead of collapsing as it should.

In this http://jsfiddle.net/syEM3/4/  click on any of the Click Here to READ MORE...
Notice how the Collapse Text shows up at the bottom of the paragraphs and doesn't disappear. Click on the Collapse and it reveal more text.

How do I prevent this and getting to work as it should?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two slideDown function calls are not specific to the .reveal and/or .collapse that you are currently doing. i.e.

```
$(".collapse").slideDown(100);
```

will find all the elements with the class .collapse on the page, and slide them down. irrespective of what element you just clicked.

I would change the slideDown call to be relavant to the element you just clicked i.e. something like this

```
$('.reveal').click(function() {
    $(this).slideUp(100);
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
    $(this).next().next(".collapse").slideToggle(100);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code

```
 $('.reveal').click(function() {
    $(this).slideUp(100);
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
    $(".collapse").slideDown(100);
 });
 $('.collapse').click(function() {
    $(this).slideUp(100);
    $(this).prev().slideToggle();
     $(".reveal").slideDown(100);
 });
```

this two rows doesn’t do what you want as they act on all elements of the specified class

```
     $(".reveal").slideDown(100);
    $(".collapse").slideDown(100);
```

Comment: Oh I see.  So they each have to be it's own ID?  I was thinking you can use class in multiple places.

Comment: you could use them that way but you have to be more spcific in your queries, a jquery query takes an second arguemnt that specifies the scope of the query. like this Query(".collapse", this); asuming that .collapse is a child element to this

Answer (score 0):

When you do `$(".collapse").slideDown(100);`, jQuery runs slideDown on everything with the .collapse class, not just the one that's related to your current this. To fix this, refer to the collapse based on its location to `$(this)`.

Do do this, use something like `$(this).siblings(".collapse").slideDown(100);`

Note that this particular selector will only work if you enclose each text block in its own div. With each text element in its own div, like you have it now, `.siblings(".collapse")`, which selects all the siblings of `$(this)` with the `collapse` class, will still select both of the `collapse` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think you should take a different approach to your problem.

See, jQuery basically has two purposes:

- Selecting one or more DOM elements from your HTML page
- manipulate the selected elements in some way

This can be repeated multiple times, since jQuery functions are chainable (this means you can call function after function after function...).

---

If I understood your problem correctly, you are trying to build a list of blog posts and only display teasers of them.
After the user clicks the "read more" button, the complete article gets expanded.

Keep in mind: jQuery selects your elements very much like CSS would do. This makes it extremely easy to
come up with a query for certain elements, but you need to structure your HTML in a good way, like
you would do for formatting reasons.

So I suggest you should use this basic markup for each of your articles (heads up, HTML5 at work!):

```
<article class="article">
    <section class="teaser">
        Hey, I am a incredible teaser text! I just introduce you to the article.
    </section>
    <section class="full">
        I am the articles body text. You should not see me initially.
    </section>
</article>
```

You can replace the `article` and `section` elements with `div` elements if you like to.

And here is the CSS for this markup:

```
/* In case you want to display multiple articles underneath, separate them a bit */
.article{
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

/* we want the teaser to stand out a bit, so we format it bold */
.teaser{
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* The article body should be a bit separated from the teaser */
.full{
    padding-top: 10px;
}

/* This class is used to hide elements */
.hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

The way we created the markup and CSS allows us to put multiple articles underneath.

Okay, you may have noticed: I completely omitted any "read more" or "collapse" buttons. This is done by intention.

If somebody visits the blog site with javascript disabled (maybe a search engine, or a old mobile which doesn't support JS or whatever),
the logic would be broken. Also, many text-snippets like "read more" and "collapse" are not relevant if they don't actually do anything and are not part of the article.

Initially, no article body is hidden, since we didn't apply the `hidden` css class anywhere. If we would
have embedded it in the HTML and someone really has no JavaScript, he would be unable to read anything.

### Adding some jQuery magic

At the bottom of the page, we are embedding the jQuery library from the google CDN.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This is a best practice and will normally speed up your page loading time. Since MANY websites are embedding
jQuery through this URL, chances are high that its already in the visitors browser cache and doesn't have
to be downloaded another time.

Notice that the `http:` at the beginning of the URL is omitted. This causes browsers to use the pages current protocol,
may it be `http` or `https`. If you would try and embed the jQuery lib via `http` protocol on a `https` website, some browsers will refuse to download the file from a unsecure connection.

After you included jQuery into the page, we are going to add our logic into a script tag. Normally we would
save the logic into a separate file (again caching and what not all), but this time a script block will do fine.

#### Finally some JavaScript

At first, we want to hide all elements with the css-class `full`, since only teasers should remain displayed. This is very easy with jQuery:

```
$('.full').hide();
```

The beginning of the script `$('.full')` tells jQuery: I need all elements with the CSS-class `full`. Then we call a function on that result, namingly `hide()` which purpose should be clear.

Okay, in the next step, we want to add some "read more" buttons, next to every teaser. Thats an easy task, too:

```
$('.teaser').after('<button class="more">Read more</button>');
```

We now select every element with the css-class `teaser` and append some HTML code `after()` each element - a button with the css-class `more`.

In the next step, we tell jQuery to observe clicks on every one of this freshly created buttons. When a user has clicked, we want to expand the next element with the css-class `full` after the clicked button.

```
$('.more').on('click', function(){
    //"this" is a reference to the button element!
    $(this).slideUp().next('.full').slideDown();
});
```

Phew, what did we do here?
First, we told jQuery that we wanted to manipulate `this`, which is a reference to the clicked button. Then we told
jQuery to hide that button (since its not needed anymore) slowly with `slideUp()`.

We immediately continued telling jQuery what to do: Now take the `next()` element (with the css-class `full`) and make it visible by sliding it down with `slideDown()`.

Thats the power of jQuerys chaining!

#### Hiding again

But wait, you wanted to be able to collapse the articles again! So we need a "collapse" button, too and
some more JavaScript:

```
$('.full').append('<button class="collapse">Collapse text</button>');
```

Note: we didn't use the `after()` function to add this button, but the `append()` function to place the button
INSIDE every element with the css-class `full`, rather than next to it. This is because we want the
collapse buttons to be hidden with the full texts, too.

Now we need to have some action when the user clicks one of those buttons, too:

```
$('.collapse').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().slideUp().prev('.more').slideDown();
});
```

Now, this was easy: We start with the button element, move the focus to its `parent()` (which is the element that contains the full text) and tell jQuery to hide that element by sliding it up with `slideUp()`.

Then we move the focus from the full-text container to its previous element with the css-class `more`, which is its expanding button that has been hidden when expanding the text. We slowly show that button again by calling `slideDown()`.

Thats it :)
I've uploaded my example on [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/ilazut/1).